# How do I build a patterned matrix (high-pass and/or low-pass filter bank)?

Tags: matrix, signal-processing

I would like the shortest code to build the following matrices, of arbitrary dimension $N$:

A **Low-Pass** filter bank matrix is of the form

$ \begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 1      & 0      & 0      & \dots  & 0  & 0  & 0 \\
            & 1      & 1      & 0      & \dots  & 0  & 0  & 0 \\
            &        &1       & 1      & \dots  & 0  & 0  & 0 \\
            &        &        &        & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
            &        &        &        & \dots  & 1  & 1  & 0  \\
            &        &        &        & \dots  &    & 1  & 1  \\
            &        &        &        & \dots  &    &    & 1
\end{bmatrix} _{N\times N} $

A **High-Pass** filter bank matrix is of the form:

$ \begin{bmatrix}
    1      & -1     & 0      & 0      & \dots  & 0  & 0  & 0 \\
           & 1      & -1      & 0      & \dots  & 0  & 0  & 0 \\
           &        &1       & -1      & \dots  & 0  & 0  & 0 \\
           &        &        &        & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
           &        &        &        & \dots  & 1  & -1  & 0  \\
           &        &        &        & \dots  &    & 1  & -1  \\
           &        &        &        & \dots  &    &    & 1
\end{bmatrix} _{N\times N} $

How can I build the above matrices for any dimension $N$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking your self-answer as a guide you can still use [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) and [`Band`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Band.html)

```
n = 5;

SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 1, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1}, {n, n}] // Grid
```

$\begin{matrix}
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}$

```
SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 1, Band[{1, 2}] -> -1}, {n, n}] // Grid
```

$\begin{matrix}
 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}$

Use [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) to convert to a standard list-of-lists if you need it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the lower triangle needs to be all ZEROS.  Thanks though :)

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use `DiagonalMatrix`

```
n = 5; 
DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, n]] + DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[-1, n - 1], 1]
```

for the highpass and

```
DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, n]] + DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1, n - 1], 1]
```

for the lowpass.

Answer (score 4):

Also for fun:

```
lowpass[n_Integer] := ToeplitzMatrix[UnitVector[n, 1], PadRight[{1, 1}, n]]

highpass[n_Integer] := ToeplitzMatrix[UnitVector[n, 1], PadRight[{1, -1}, n]]
```

In practice, I'd use Wizard's route, however.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the LaTeX edit you made to my answer.  I just copied what *Mathematica* gave me; is it inferior somehow?

Comment: It's just that the `matrix` environment tends to be less finicky than the more general `array`. OTOH, I suppose *Mathematica* is not aware of the AMS extension to $\LaTeX$, which is why it sticks with `array` and compensates with all those alignment instructions (those multiple `c`'s you may have noticed).

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.  The result used Table[]  and If[]

To get the low pass, use:

```
Table[If[i == j, 1, 0] + If[i == j - 1, 1, 0], {i, N}, {j, N}]
```

To get the high pass, use:

```
Table[If[i == j, 1, 0] + If[i == j - 1, -1, 0], {i, N}, {j, N}]
```

Comment: FYI: You should not use `N` like this as it is a reserved Symbol.

Comment: By the way: +1 for bothering to self answer, and welcome to the site.

Comment: Alternatively, `Table[KroneckerDelta[i, j] + KroneckerDelta[i, j - 1], {i, n}, {j, n}]` and `Table[KroneckerDelta[i, j] - KroneckerDelta[i, j - 1], {i, n}, {j, n}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for the help!  And I will not use N like that :)

Answer (score 3):

For fun:

```
With[{n = 5}, ArrayPad[{1, 1}, {# - 1, n - # - 1}] & /@ Range[n]] // Grid
With[{n = 5}, ArrayPad[{1, -1}, {# - 1, n - # - 1}] & /@ Range[n]] // Grid
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 5;
ReplacePart[IdentityMatrix[n], {i_, j_ } /; j == i + 1 -> 1] // Grid
ReplacePart[IdentityMatrix[n], {i_, j_ } /; j == i + 1 -> -1] // Grid
```