# How can I assign matrix values in below form?

Tags: matrix

[image]

I want to create matrix as the below fig. shows.  How can I do it with a do-loop, for-loop, if-loop, or any other way? Thanks a lot...

Comment: It's an straightforward usage of `SparseArray[ ]`

Comment: Or `DiagonalMatrix` with the second argument set to `1` or `-1`.

Comment: Related: [(92776)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92776/constructing-tri-diagonal-matrices), [(107714)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107714/constructing-a-large-tridiagonal-matrix-with-alternating-signs/), [(107530)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107530/how-do-i-build-a-patterned-matrix-high-pass-and-or-low-pass-filter-bank/).

Answer (score 6):

```
myMatrix[d_] := With[{c = (1/(Sqrt[2 # - 3] Sqrt[2 # - 1])) & /@ Range[2, d]},
     SparseArray[{
        {1, 1} -> 1, 
        Band[{1, 2}] -> c, 
        Band[{2, 1}] -> -c
        }, {d, d}]
];

myMatrix[5] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: You beat me to the punch :-) and using `Band` too, which is neater than my solution. I'll delete my answer unless I can come up with something else

Comment: @Marco, you didn't need to remove it; it's nice to show the formulation with entry-by-entry rules for completeness.

Comment: @J.M. I see your point. I'll undelete it, thanks! Besides, Xavier's `myMatrix` was feeling lonely anyway. I wonder if we could convince march to go for `ourMatrix` :-)

Comment: Shorter: `c = 1/Sqrt[4 Range[d - 1]^2 - 1]`

Answer (score 6):

```
yourMatrix[n_Integer] := SparseArray[{
    {1, 1} -> 1,
    {i_, j_} /; j == i - 1 -> -1/Sqrt[(2 i - 3) (2 i - 1)],
    {i_, j_} /; j == i + 1 -> 1/Sqrt[(2 j - 3) (2 j - 1)]
    }, {n, n}] // Normal

yourMatrix[5] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Slightly obfuscated: `yourMatrix[n_Integer] := SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 1, {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 1 :> Sign[j - i]/Sqrt[4 Min[i, j]^2 - 1]}, {n, n}] // Normal`

Comment: A big +1 for "fit[ing] the pattern" :D

Comment: @Xavier I'm glad you liked my edit: I thought it would blend in better :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
ourMatrix[m_] :=
  DiagonalMatrix[UnitVector[m, 1]] + # - Transpose[#] &
    @DiagonalMatrix[1/Sqrt[#1 #2] & @@@ Partition[Range[1, 2 m - 1, 2], 2, 1], 1]
```

(Thanks to MarcoB for the heads-up about the missing `1` and J.M. for the fix; thus the `ourMatrix`.)

```
ourMatrix[5]
```

[image]

Comment: It's nice to see a `DiagonalMatrix` approach as well. The OP's matrix has a $1$ entry in position (1, 1) though. Could you adjust your solution accordingly?

Comment: A simple cure involves `DiagonalMatrix[UnitVector[m, 1]]`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, @MarcoB.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, and for displaying excellent taste in variable names! What a nice, cozy family of little matrices we have on this page! :-)

Comment: I concur with @MarcoB, this is a function with an exquisite name :p